# How can I get mongoDB's aggregate pipeline to calculate outputs?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm new to mongoDB databases, and I have been trying to do two functions within a mongoDB database storing shop invoices. The first function is an aggregate pipeline function that returns all invoice items with a quantity of more than 1 within each invoice, and the second function is a MapReduce function using the aggregate pipeline that adds up the total amount of money spent in an invoice by multiplying the unit price of each item by the quantity purchased and adding all of these item prices together.

My problem is that while the aggregate pipeline is returning things in both cases, it doesn't seem to be doing the actual filtering and calculations I want it to do. For the avoidance of doubt, I was able to successfully populate the database with invoices and successfully find a specific invoice number and display all its associated info using a .find() query, so the issue seems to be in the aggregate pipeline rather than any earlier issue with the database items themselves or finding those.

For the first aggregation function, here is the code I tried:

```
print("Results of aggregation: ");

cursorAggregate = db.Collection_Invoice.aggregate([
    {
     $match: {
        "Invoice_Items.Quantity" : { $gt : 1 }
     }
    },
    {
     $project: {
        "Cust_Num" : 1,
        "Inv_Num" : 1,
        "Invoice_Items" : {
          $filter : {
            input : "$Invoice_Items",
            as: "item",
            cond: { $gt: ["$item,Quantity", 1] }
               }
            }
        }
    }
]);

cursorAggregate.forEach(printjson);
```

I was hoping that it would output all of the invoice items with a quantity of greater than 1 within each invoice (for the avoidance of doubt, there were some stored within Invoice_Items for both invoices). However, Invoice_Items returned empty for both invoices.

For the second aggregation function using MapReduce, here is the code I tried:

```
print("Results of MapReduce: ");

cursorMapReduce = db.Collection_Invoice.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "Cust_Num": 1,
      "Inv_Num": 1,
      "Total Spent": {
        $sum: {
          $map: {
            input: "$Invoice_Items",
            as: "item",
            in: { $multiply: ["$item.Unit_Price", "$item.Quantity"] }
          }
        }
      },
      "Invoice_Items": 1
    }
  }
]);

cursorMapReduce.forEach(printjson);
```

I was hoping that this code would multiply the unit price of each item purchased within an invoice by the quantity purchased and add all of these together to calculate the total amount of money spent by each customer.

When I ran the code, MapReduce found the invoices correctly and displayed the items correctly, but did not do the mathematical function I wanted (multiplying the unit price by the quantity for each item and adding all the item prices together to work out the total price of each invoice), with "Total Spent: 0" being returned for both customers even though the invoices above showed correctly and showed the item prices and quantities purchased by each customer.

Does anyone know what the problem might be? As far as I can tell from internet research, I've constructed my aggregation queries correctly, so I was confused.

Any advice is much appreciated.

**EDIT** - I feel I should include the full code, show some output shots and further clarify the problems I am experiencing.

Here is the full code I have been using:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('dbSales');

print("You are now connected to database : " + db);

db.Collection_Invoice.drop();

invoice1 =  
        { 
            "Inv_Num"       : "Inv0045",
            "Cust_Num"      : "Cust009",
            "First_Name"    : "David",           
            "Last_Name"     : "Beckham",
            "Addr_Line1"    : "25 Orchard Road",             
            "City"          : "London",          
            "Postcode"      : "E8 4PQ",
            "Invoice_Date"  : new Date("01/01/2015"),
            "Invoice_Items" :   [
                                    {
                                        "Item_Code"     : "Item0082",
                                        "Item_Name"     : "Stapler",
                                        "Unit_Price"    : 1.25,
                                        "Quantity"      : 2
                                    },
                                    {
                                         "Item_Code"     : "Item5829",
                                         "Item_Name"     : "Shirt",
                                         "Unit_Price"    : 10,
                                         "Quantity"      : 1
                                    }
                                ]
        };

       
invoice2 = 
        { 
            "Inv_Num"       : "Inv0046",
            "Cust_Num"      : "Cust058",
            "First_Name"    : "John",
            "Last_Name"     : "Donne",
            "Addr_Line1"    : "154 Yew Tree Way",
            "City"          : "Cheltenham",
            "Postcode"      : "GL51 4PQ",
            "Invoice_Date"  : new Date("01/01/2015"),
            "Invoice_Items" :       [
                                    {
                                    "Item_Code"     : "Item0015",
                                    "Item_Name"     : "Mobile",
                                    "Unit_Price"    : 75.00,
                                    "Quantity"      : 2
                                },
                                {
                                    "Item_Code"     : "Item0542",
                                    "Item_Name"     : "Shoe",
                                    "Unit_Price"    : 25.00,
                                    "Quantity"      : 1
                                },
                                {
                                    "Item_Code"     : "Item5829",
                                    "Item_Name"     : "Shirt",
                                    "Unit_Price"    : 10,
                                    "Quantity"      : 2
                                }
                            ]
    };

       

db.Collection_Invoice.insert(invoice1);

db.Collection_Invoice.insert(invoice2);



cursor = db.Collection_Invoice.find(); 

cursor.forEach(printjson);

print("Results of query with parameter ");

cursor = db.Collection_Invoice.find({"Inv_Num"      : "Inv0045"}); 

cursor.forEach(printjson);

print("Results of aggregation: ");

cursorAggregate = db.Collection_Invoice.aggregate([
    {
     $match: {
        "Invoice_Items.Quantity" : { $gt : 1 }
     }
     },
    {
     $project: {
        "Cust_Num" : 1,
        "Inv_Num" : 1,
        "Invoice_Items" : {
          $filter : {
            input : "$Invoice_Items",
            as: "item",
            cond: { $gt: ["$item,Quantity", 1] }
               }
            }
        }
    }
]);

cursorAggregate.forEach(printjson);

print("Results of MapReduce: ");

cursorMapReduce = db.Collection_Invoice.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "Cust_Num": 1,
      "Inv_Num": 1,
      "Total Spent": {
        $sum: {
          $map: {
            input: "$Invoice_Items",
            as: "item",
            in: { $multiply: ["$item.Unit_Price", "$item.Quantity"] }
          }
        }
      },
      "Invoice_Items": 1
    }
  }
]);

cursorMapReduce.forEach(printjson);
```

Here is the output of the first pipeline:

```
Results of aggregation:
{
  _id: ObjectId("6529893bf7c8411b42e1a641"),
  Inv_Num: 'Inv0045',
  Cust_Num: 'Cust009',
  Invoice_Items: []
}
{
  _id: ObjectId("6529893bf7c8411b42e1a642"),
  Inv_Num: 'Inv0046',
  Cust_Num: 'Cust058',
  Invoice_Items: []
}
```

The intent here is that the Invoice_Items variable for each customer would display all invoice items with a quantity of more than 1, but as can be seen, the Invoice_Items variable is showing as an empty list instead.

Here is the output of the second pipeline that used MapReduce:

```
Results of MapReduce:
{
  _id: ObjectId("6529893bf7c8411b42e1a641"),
  Inv_Num: 'Inv0045',
  Cust_Num: 'Cust009',
  Invoice_Items: [
    {
      Item_Code: 'Item0082',
      Item_Name: 'Stapler',
      Unit_Price: 1.25,
      Quantity: 2
    }
    {
      Item_Code: 'Item5829',
      Item_Name: 'Shirt',
      Unit_Price: 10,
      Quantity: 1
    }
  ],
  'Total Spent': 0
}
{
  _id: ObjectId("6529893bf7c8411b42e1a642"),
  Inv_Num: 'Inv0046',
  Cust_Num: 'Cust058',
  Invoice_Items: [
    {
      Item_Code: 'Item0015',
      Item_Name: 'Mobile',
      Unit_Price: 75,
      Quantity: 2
    },
    {
      Item_Code: 'Item0542',
      Item_Name: 'Shoe',
      Unit_Price: 25,
      Quantity: 1
    },
    {
      Item_Code: 'Item5829',
      Item_Name: 'Shirt',
      Unit_Price: 10,
      Quantity: 2
    }
  ],
  'Total Spent': 0
}
```

The intent here is that the total spend for each customer would be added up across all of their items, so in the instance displayed above, the total spend for the first customer would be listed as 12.50 and the spend for the second customer would be listed as 195. However, the aggregation pipeline is simply outputting the total spend for both as 0 despite the items in each invoice and their prices being displayed above.

Comment: It's not really effective to try and debug this without sample documents. Can you create a mongoplayground that demonstrates the problem with the first pipeline? At a glance, it feels like you can (and should) use aggregation for the second use case as well

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have now added in screenshots of the outputs I was receiving alongside explanations of why they're wrong, if that helps at all.

Comment: Can you please try to include the actual code in your question instead of images because code in images can't be copied and pasted into an editor and compiled in order to reproduce the problem. Among many other reasons why it's not generally recommended to post images of code here on SO, images are large and hard to read on mobile devices, they can't be searched and therefore aren't useful to future readers. https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Also what you've provided is the _output_, but we also need examples of the _input_. And echoing @chridam's sentiment, I'm certainly not going to go through the effort of manually transposing your images into text so that I can reproduce the situation. Help us help you.

Comment: My apologies for the earlier inconvenience. I have now edited my post to include the whole code I was using, including the data inputs used, and I have also placed my outputs within code blocks rather than images. I hope that's easier to work with.

Comment: I should also clarify that I saved the code as a JavaScript file and executed it by calling Mongosh from within the Command Prompt terminal.

Comment: Looks like the first aggregation has a typo. `"$item,Quantity"` should be `"$$item.Quantity"` (period instead of comma and add a dollar sign)

Comment: You have the same missing dollar sign in the second aggregation. `item` has been defined as [a local user variable](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/) at that point inside the `$map` operator so you need to refer to it with two dollar signs instead of one - `$$item`. By the way, that second operation is a standard aggregation that uses the `$map` operator, but it is _not_ Map-Reduce (which is [a deprecated functionality in MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/map-reduce/))

Comment: This solved my problem perfectly; thank you very much!